# Customize fncychap head

Tags: header-footer, chapters, fncychap

I am currently formating my Phd thesis for book publication and using the Lenny style from fncychap package for my chapter headings. However, I am struggling with the customization of the heads of the text pages. Here is a short example code:

```
\documentclass[11pt]{book}
\usepackage{scrpage2}
\usepackage[paperwidth=176mm,paperheight=246mm]{geometry}
\setlength{\textheight}{19.5cm}
\setlength{\footskip}{8mm}
\setlength{\parindent}{0pt}
\setlength{\textwidth}{12.5cm}
\setlength{\evensidemargin}{0cm}
\setlength{\oddsidemargin}{0cm}
\setlength{\headsep}{0.6cm}
\setlength{\headheight}{0.4cm}
\setlength{\topmargin}{-0.9cm}

\usepackage[utf8]{inputenc}
\usepackage[english]{babel} 

\usepackage[Lenny]{fncychap}

\usepackage{lipsum}

\begin{document}
\tableofcontents

\chapter*{Book summary}
\addcontentsline{toc}{chapter}{Book summary}
\chaptermark{Book summary}
\lipsum[1-12]

\chapter{Introduction}
\section{Section 1}
\lipsum[1-6]
\section{Section 2}
\lipsum[1-6]

\end{document}
```

I want to make the following adjustments:

- In the preface "Book summary", I want to delete "Chapter 0." from the head of the text pages resulting simply in "BOOK SUMMARY".
- In the following chapters (e.g., Introduction), I want to delete "Chapter" from the head of the    text pages, but not from the chapter title page. The chapter front page should look similar to now, but the head on the following pages should be: 8 (Page number) 1. INTRODUCTION

I got to delete "Chapter" in the header. However, it then also disappeared in the header of the chapter title page. Also the "0." in "Book summary" remained.